Layer expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors
I am trying to build model to predict posts likes, the model takes text and content type which is one hot encoded column.
I have made a TensorFlow dataset but when trying to fit the model I got this error:
Layer "functional_13" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. 
Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'data:0' shape=(None, 1000) dtype=int64>]

Here is some snippets of my code:
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((vectorized_text,
                                             content,
                                             df['likes_rate']))

dataset= dataset.cache()
dataset= dataset.shuffle(160000)
dataset= dataset.batch(16)
dataset= dataset.prefetch(8)

This is my model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Concatenate,LSTM,Bidirectional
text_input= Input(shape=(1000,))
content_input=Input(shape=(3,))

text_embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(Max_Features+1, 32)(text_input)  # Adjust embedding dim
lstm= Bidirectional(LSTM(32,activation='tanh'))(text_embeddings)
# Concatenate text embeddings and content features
combined_features = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([lstm, content_input])

# Hidden layers (adjust number/activation functions)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(combined_features)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
# Output layer for likes prediction
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)

I want to make an embedding layer to for the text then pass it to LSTM then combine the output of the LSTM and the contnent to Dense layers.
When trying to fit the model I am getting the problem above.
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[text_input, content_input], outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='Adam')
model.fit(dataset,epochs=10)

If I iterate over the dataset. The code works correctly. But .fit every time make a random weights so the model make no progress.
for text_batch, content_batch, y_batch in dataset:
    # Train model on the current batch
    model.fit(x=[text_batch, content_batch], y=y_batch)


The problem is that tensorflow needs one value for the input, one for the output, currently your dataset will return three. You need to combine the first two:
You canset up your dataset like this by zipping the values.
X1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(vectorized_text)
X2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(content)
X = tf.data.Dataset.zip((X1,X2))
Y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(likes)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((X, Y))

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[text_input, content_input], outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='Adam')
model.fit(dataset, epochs=10)

